# RAM works with 3200Mhz out of the box, do I still need to enable D.O.C.P/XMP Profile

Tags: memory, asus, xmp

I've two RAMs:

**Team Group Elite Plus 8 GB DDR4 3200mhz**

When I installed them in my PC, the **Windows Task Manager** shows :

[image]

The **CPU-Z** shows :

[image]

When I open the Bios, I don't find any profile under the D.O.C.P to select, the only option is **DISABLED** :

[image]

The SPD Profiles :

[image]

Comment: DDR4 goes up to 3200MHz using standard JEDEC profiles. you only need XMP/DOCP if your RAM is faster than that (and your Mobo/CPU support the faster speed). if you look at the SPD tab in CPU-Z you should see info on your SPD profiles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM#JEDEC_standard_DDR4_module

Comment: @FrankThomas thank you so much for your info, I've added the SPD Profiles screenshots, you can check it out

Comment: yep, that JEDEC #12 is the one! everything looks fine.

Comment: @FrankThomas massive thanks for your help